# Locating the ROM address of a RAM variable

Tags: c, linker, arm, embedded

I'm wondering if there's a way to obtain the ROM address used to seed the initial value of a RAM variable? Given a statement `static uint32_t foo = 0x12345678;` the initial value `0x12345678` is present as ROM somewhere to serve as the initial value at `&foo`. At some point in time I'd like to be able to reset the value of `foo` to it's initial state.

I could create a second variable `const static uint32_t initial_foo = 0x12345678;` to use but that will then double the ROM data space needed to store variables for this use case.

Can the offset `&foo` from the beginning of RAM (or more specifically `&_srelocate`, see the linker script below) be reliably correlated with one of the symbols in ROM space?

Selected parts of the ARM/GNU C linker v 6.3.1 script are below.

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
SEARCH_DIR(.)

/* Memory Spaces Definitions */
MEMORY
{
  rom (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00400000, LENGTH = 0x00100000
  ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00020000
}

/* The stack size used by the application. NOTE: you need to adjust according to your application. */
__stack_size__ = DEFINED(__stack_size__) ? __stack_size__ : 0x3000;
__ram_end__ = ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram) - 4;

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sfixed = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
        *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
        *(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7)
        *(.rodata .rodata* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)

        /* Support C constructors, and C destructors in both user code
           and the C library. This also provides support for C++ code. */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.init))
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __preinit_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
        __preinit_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __init_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array))
        __init_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(0x4);
        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .ctors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.ctors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __fini_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.fini_array))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        __fini_array_end = .;

        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .dtors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.dtors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _efixed = .;            /* End of text section */
    } > rom

    /* .ARM.exidx is sorted, so has to go in its own output section.  */
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_start = .);
    .ARM.exidx :
    {
      *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > rom
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_end = .);

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;

    .relocate : AT (_etext)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _srelocate = .;
        *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
        *(.data .data.*);
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _erelocate = .;
    } > ram

    /* .bss and stack sections removed */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _end = . ;
}
```

Comment: If you just write the assignment `foo = 0x12345678;`, will the compiler not reinitialize the variable in the most efficient way?

Comment: You could get the address of the variable from the ROM through the linker script and do a `memcpy` at runtime to RAM. Definitely Lundin's answer is easier and faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having one RAM variable `type foo = value;`, simply make one variable `const type foo = value;` and ensure it is allocated in ROM (should be the case if the variable has static storage duration). Then manually copy it to RAM as needed. This way the value is only stored once in ROM; initializers of ROM variables are not stored separately.

Then you won't be wasting any memory and you won't have to worry about somehow searching through `.rodata` for the initializer value, which would be rather questionable practice.

Comment: Yes good point. The default value of the RAM based variable can be left unspecified and explicitly copied from ROM during initialization or reset of the module.

Comment: The code to copy the value will require more ROM space than having the value stored twice (initialiser plus `const` var). Better use a macro for the value, an initialiser (which is very efficient if you have more than 2 or 3 variables) and just assign it if you have to "reset" the value. This avoids redundancy for the value and lets the compiler decide how to do the assignment.

Comment: The `uint32_t` example above was just to serve as an example. More complex `struct` types consume more memory thus the motivation to avoid unnecessary copies. I don't think the ARM/GNU C (or any) compiler resolves recurring uses of a macro literal to the same memory address, thus ROM copies would be produced at each use. Using 50 `"foo"` literals for example, produces 50 instances of `"foo"` in ROM last time I checked.

Comment: @mje: Yeah, that is a bit more complex. Nevertheless, without more information, this could be an XY problem. It's in general not good practice to have extensive global (non-`const`) variables.

Comment: @Olaf No, naturally an extra initializer is _not_ stored in ROM, as that would be pointless. That's not how code is generated on any ROM-based system I have ever seen.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm not sure what you're replying to. On most (if not all) MCU I've met, initialiser data is stored in ROM. As well as any other constant data like string literals or `const` variables. There are only two exceptions: explicitly moving `const` vars to RAM using a special sections, a modified linker script and startup code (used if Flash speed is a bottleneck) and systems which can't access data from Flash (e.g. true Harvard architectures).